# Function parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, auto, variadic-functions

I recently saw the following code excerpt in the Working Draft, Standard for Programming Language C++ (dated 2016-05-30, page 96).

```
auto vglambda = [](auto printer) {
    return [=](auto&& ... ts) { // OK: ts is a function parameter pack
        printer(std::forward<decltype(ts)>(ts)...);
        return [=]() {
            printer(ts ...);
        };
    };
};
```

I cannot make sense of the ellipses here. They are not old ellipses in the 'C' sense since they are being expanded. They are not parameter pack in the sense of the "template parameter pack" since there is no template to be seen. In the comment it refers to these as a function parameter pack.

I investigated to see if I could define a regular function with a parameter pack.

```
void f(auto&& ...ts) {} // error
```

which did not compile but

```
auto k = [](auto&& ...ts){};
```

compiles fine and I can call it as expected

```
k(1, 2, 3);
```

It appears to me that this is just a template parameter pack in disguise as lambdas are functors in disguise. Thus, it is only possible with lambda expressions.

I would appreciate clarifications and/or elucidations.

Comment: A lambda with `auto` in the parameter list is a generic lambda, i.e. an unnamed local class with an `operator()()` function _template_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`auto` lambdas where added in C++14.

This permits you to create lambdas with a `template operator()`.

You do this with the

```
[](auto x){}
[](auto...xs){}
[](auto& xs){}
[](auto&...xs){}
[](auto&& xs){}
[](auto&&...xs){}
[](auto const& xs){}
[](auto const&...xs){}
```

syntaxes.  Note that non-template arguments can be added (the above is not exhastive).  These correspond to `auto` being mapped to an implicit template type argument.

There is some talk of expanding this to normal functions in the concepts proposal, which was deferred in C++14, C++17 and is now a TS possible in C++20.

Comment: Thanks. For those who like C++ standard : 5.1.5-6 "for a generic lambda, the closure type has a public inline function call
operator member template (14.5.2) whose template-parameter-list consists of one invented type template parameter
for each occurrence of auto in the lambda’s parameter-declaration-clause, in order of appearance. The invented type template-parameter is a parameter pack if the corresponding parameter-declaration declares a function parameter pack (8.3.5)."